# Properties of determinants in different spaces.

Tags: proof-writing, vector-analysis, problem-solving

Suppose that

$$ \mathbf A =(A_1, A_2,A_3) $$
$$ \mathbf B =(B_2, B_2,B_3) $$
$$ \mathbf C =(C_3, C_2,C_3) $$

We know that 
$$ \mathbf{A \cdot B \times C} $$

is equal to

$$\begin{vmatrix} A_x & A_y & A_z \\ B_x & B_y & B_z & \\ C_x & C_y & C_z\end{vmatrix}$$

However, suppose that we change the basis of the space to three arbitrary vectors, 
$$ \mathbf { \vec{a},\vec b,\vec c}$$

show that

$$ \mathbf{A \cdot B \times C} $$

is transformed into

$$\begin{vmatrix} A_x & A_y & A_z \\ B_x & B_y & B_z & \\ C_x & C_y & C_z\end{vmatrix} (\mathbf{a \cdot b \times c)}$$

So is this transformation somewhat of a linear one, and how do I prove this statement? I tried with components, but I think there must be a most straightforward way that doesn't involve all of these componente.